# php mail function is working fine on own email id but not working on other domain mail

Tags: php, email

Commented `to2` variable is working fine. But `Gmail id` is not working.
When I'm executing this code then first condition is printing `Yes` and second variable is printing `No`:

```
$to = "info@ebitmoney.com";
//$to2= "enquiry@ebitmoney.com";  //this variable is working
$to2= "abhisekh.milkyway@gmail.com"; // this is not working

$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "hello";

$header = "From: abhishek@milkywayservices.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

$send1=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
$send=mail($to2,$subject,$message,$header);

if($send1){
    echo 'Yes';
}
else{
    echo 'No';
}

if($send){
    echo 'Yes';
}
else{
    echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error messages? Or do you simply don't get any mails? I guess your sending mail server is not configured correctly and gmail rejects your mail because they are pretty strict.

Comment: no i have not any error messages

Comment: This is not something you could fix with php.You should check with the email service on your server/pc.If linux then try `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//$to = "info@ebitmoney.com";
//$to2= "enquiry@ebitmoney.com";  //this variable is working
//$to2= "abhisekh.milkyway@gmail.com"; // this is not working
$email_to = "info@ebitmoney.com, abhisekh.milkyway@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "hello";

$header = "From: abhishek@milkywayservices.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

$send1=mail($email_to,$subject,$message,$header);
$send=mail($to2,$subject,$message,$header);

if($send1){
    echo 'Yes';
}
else{
    echo 'No';
}

if($send){
    echo 'Yes';
}
else{
    echo 'No';
}
```

If this doen't work, probably the problem is with your SMTP settings.
Please post your SMTP settings here. (Don't post the password..)

Comment: No  this formate  "info@ebitmoney.com, abhisekh.milkyway@gmail.com" is not working